# Place an icon to top-right of an absolutely positioned image

Tags: css, css-position

I saw many similar questions and answers but nothing is same as what I am trying to achieve.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">

    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="http://fpoimg.com/600x300" alt=""/>
      <a href="" class="close-link">x</a>
    </div>

    <div>image name</div>
    <div>id: 123456</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
  * {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  .container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

  }

  img {
    max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
  }

  .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

See the jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/61afw70q/10/

What I need to do is place the red cross button to top-right of the IMAGE. Note - i don't want to place it to top-right of container. I want it for the image. Every image will be different in size. Image centers within the container.

This is highly stripped down version of my entire page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `inner` div...you have the image in a container and so there is no need to position the image either.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.close-link {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://fpoimg.com/600x300" alt="" />
    <a href="" class="close-link">x</a>
  </div>


  <div>image name</div>
  <div>id: 123456</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I agree I don't need the inner div. I added it to experiment with the button position .. Any solution on how can I align the close button to image top-right ???

Comment: It is...isn't it in my demo?

Comment: yes I see it now. Thanks. Let me verify in my source code to mark as answer.

Comment: Thank you for the time, but it is not correct. It only looks correct. Change the image size (or the container size), you will see that the close button is aligned to the container. I want it aligned to the corner of image (once again, container size and image size either of these can change).

Comment: The image-container needs to be inline-block so it shrink wraps around the image...Here's a simplified version - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZOWXrG

Comment: Doing like this changes my container size if a bigger image is placed. Can you suggest if am trying to achieve something not possible at all ?

Comment: The image-container MUST shrink wrap around the image to restrict the position of the close button. If this is a problem you might have to re-think the way you are doing this.

Comment: I know the simple version. My problem is coming exactly because of the other flex elements and the two lines of text which must be present on page. The entire scenario is like this : Container width and height is variable, Image width and height is variable. There are 2 lines of text below the image, Image must take entire available remaining area without increasing the container width or height. and then the close button should align to top right of image. See my original fiddle, everything is correct except the close icon button.Try changing container size or image size and see what I need.

Comment: Then I would suggest that your issue isn't the placing of the button, it's the sizing of the divs.

Comment: Correct, Let me try a different way, or I need to speak to the Designers to change the position ;-) .. Thank you for looking into it once again.